# Get a read-write stream from uri

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, stream, uri

Given a `Android.Net.Uri` with name `uri`, using `ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(uri)` a write-only stream is opened. And with `ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(uri)` a read-only stream is opened.

How can I get a read-write stream from a uri?

The uri local is to a simple text file  stored in a phone SDcard. The uri given in `OnActivityResult`.

Comment: Sounds like rhetorical question... Which of GET, PUT and POST you expect to produce R/W stream?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I want a R/W stream from uri.

Comment: Test if it's a file uri, and open it yourself? Otherwise you're stuck with readonly / writeonly. Java streams are typically only one or the other, hence the API design here.

Comment: Since actual answer not going to be useful to you... I'd recommend [edit] the question to clarify what type of Uri you are looking for and if it is not a local file uri what protocols are supported on the server you are trying to get R/W stream. Hopefully someone will guide you to implement one (or maybe if server support some useful protocols can suggest a library)... At least showing sample Uri can narrow down choices/"not possible" answers.